closed form of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{J_{2n-1}(z)}{2n-1}$
Does the following infinite series have a closed form:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{J_{2n-1}(z)}{2n-1}?
\end{equation} Here, $J_n$ is the Bessel function. (If the denominator does not depend on $n$, then there's a nice expression given here.)
As an aside: I'm interested in this problem because I encountered the following integral:
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\pi \cos(\cos(x))\sin(z\sin(x)) dx, 
\end{equation} which, by using Jacobi-Anger expansion, can be expressed as
\begin{equation}
2J_0(1)\sum_{n=1}^\infty J_{2n-1}(z) \int_0^\pi \sin((2n-1)x) dx \propto \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{J_{2n-1}(z)}{2n-1}.
\end{equation}

I searched through Gradshteyn and Rhyzhik and didn't find anything.

Side note - it looks very close, but not quite equal to, a rescaled version of $J_1$:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xo04lz5ije

Using the generating function for those functions:
$$\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z}J_n(x)t^n = e^{\frac x 2 \left( t - \frac 1 t\right) }$$
$$e^{\frac x 2 \left( t - \frac 1 t\right)}-e^{-\frac x 2 \left( t - \frac 1 t\right)}=\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z}J_n(x)t^n - \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z}J_n(x)(-t)^n=  2\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z}J_{2n-1}(x)t^{2n-1}$$
Furthermore, $J_{-(2n+1)}(x)=-J_{2n+1}(x)$, thus
$$e^{\frac x 2 \left( t - \frac 1 t\right)}-e^{-\frac x 2 \left( t - \frac 1 t\right)}=  2\sum_{n\geq 1}J_{2n-1}(x)\left(t^{2n-1}-\frac 1 {t^{2n-1}}\right)$$
Plugging $t=e^{i\theta}$:
$$e^{\frac x 2 \left( e^{i\theta} - e^{-i\theta}\right)}-e^{-\frac x 2 \left( e^{i\theta} - e^{-i\theta}\right)}=  2\sum_{n\geq 1}J_{2n-1}(x)\left(e^{(2n-1)i\theta}-e^{-(2n-1)i\theta}\right)$$
$$e^{ix\sin\theta }-e^{-ix\sin\theta}=  
4i\sum_{n\geq 1}J_{2n-1}(x)\sin\left((2n-1)\theta\right)$$
$$\sin(x\sin \theta) = 
2\sum_{n\geq 1}J_{2n-1}(x)\sin\left((2n-1)\theta\right)$$
Integrating w.r.t. $\theta$:
$$\int_0^\theta \sin(x\sin u)du = -2\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{J_{2n-1}(x)}{2n-1}\left[\cos\left((2n-1)\theta\right)-1\right]$$
Evaluating at $\theta=\frac \pi 2$:
$$\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \sin(x\sin u)du = 2\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{J_{2n-1}(x)}{2n-1}$$
The left-hand-side is given by the Struve function:
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{J_{2n-1}(z)}{2n-1} = \frac \pi 4 H_0(z)$$
